# I'm Interested in Virtual Reality

Tags: virtual-reality

Lately I'm interested in VR and I decided to learn more about it and technologies beyond this.

I also have a background of Mathematic science from my university field.(Applied Math.)

Can anyone suggest me some article or book or anything to learn more?

Free references preferred.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you start by actually making things in VR. To read about it and to experience it are completely different things. I personally work with Oculus Rift. It is easy to develop for it because of its integration with various game engines. But as a cheaper option you could get started with Google Cardboard.

If you want to read up about the core technology behind VR, I would suggest start by reading about Computer Graphics. After you have a grip on that you can start to explore other topics for example how tracking works, issues of FOV etc.

For readings about Graphics, I would suggest you have a look at this thread.
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12299/what-are-some-good-books-which-detail-the-fundamentals-of-graphics-processing